# Анимированное появление блока

Tags: html, jquery, css

Добрый день. Хочу реализовать анимацию появления блока при клике. Нажимаем на кнопку и блок раскрывается круговой анимацией, тем самым заполняя весь экран из верхнего левого угла (где сама кнопка расположена).
Если разбить анимацию на этапы, то вижу это так:

1. Блок скрыт (ширина и высота равны 0). Т.к. он должен быть круглым, по умолчанию border-radius равен 50%.
2. Кликаем на кнопку, блок начинает "расти".
3. Заполняет весь экран так, чтобы круглые края уходили за пределы экрана.

Вопрос вот в чем:
Каким образом сделать так, чтобы контент в этом блоке центровался относительно краев экрана, а не краев блока, т.к. блок уходит далеко за пределы экрана.

Набросал первый вариант, но мне кажется, можно проще.
[Пример](http://new.futura-studio.ru/) (кнопка в левом верхнем углу).

Comment: Ну мы не можем сказать проще это или нет. Так как мы не видим вашего варианта...

Comment: А в последнем абзаце не открывается ссылка?

Comment: kryuchkov_kv, теперь открылась

Comment: kryuchkov_kv, сделано неплохо, как по мне

Comment: Если что, нашел еще такое решение: https://codepen.io/ashwinsaxena/pen/ByMVZJ

Comment: если поменять размер окна при открытом меню - центровка сползает... а почему ширину окна берете в абсолютных цифрах, а не в процентах? ... ну, если все-таки на это есть причина - то в качестве костыля предлагаю добавить реакцию на ресайз (пересчет ширины)...

Comment: ну а вообще, если прям чтобы "стильно-модно-молодежно" - можно всю анимацию на css перетащить... но это совсем другая история... UPD: сорри, только сейчас посмотрел на "еще такое решение"... ну собсно и я об этом :))

Comment: ну а если по теме, то "отдельно круглый фон, отдельно враппер в размер экрана и содержимое по центру" - по-моему вполне нормальный вариант, куда там проще-то :)